# Swagger-ui does not display all parameters

Tags: swagger, jhipster, swagger-ui, springfox

I have generated an simple Jhipster app and i create some entity with filter.
The api-docs page only display the parameters for the two first attributes of the entities.

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U82wo.png)
This entity has :

- **integer** id

  **String** nom

  **String** description

  **integer** collaborateur_id

how can i configure Swagger-ui to see everything ?

Thanks and apologize for my English ;)

Comment: Maybe it's due to type of fields, could you edit your question with your entity definition?

Comment: Thinks.
I don't think that,
all my entities just use String and integer type.

Comment: OK, for relationships it seems normal but for simple fields it could be a bug and it should be reported on github with all required details.

Comment: bug report on github :
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6543